# Update a row dynamically using modal and javascript / JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, modal-dialog

I want to dynamically edit and update a row (category name) that i have submitted before. I can edit a row by click a edit button and show a modal with the value. But, the problem is how to submit again and replace the value (with same name input type) on selected row in table?

For example i added 3 category (category A, category B, category C). I want to edit category B into category D and submit again.

With below snippet, if you try to edit a category and submit again, it will be add new row again not replace the value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
       
        var counter = 0;

        $("#modalfrmdata").submit(function(e){  
            e.preventDefault();
            var categoryname = $("input[name='txtcategoryname']").val();  

            $('#categoryList tbody').append('<tr><td>' + categoryname + '<input type="hidden" name="categoryname[' + String(counter) + ']" value="' + categoryname + '"/></td><td class="content tengah"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalitems">Edit</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-delete">Delete</button></tr>');

            $("input[name='txtcategoryname']").val('');  

            counter++;
        });

        $("#categoryList").on("click", ".btn-delete", function(){  
            $(this).parents("tr").remove();  
        });

        $("#categoryList").on("click", ".btn-edit", function(){  
            var inputname = $(this).closest("tr").find("input").attr("name"); 
            var inputvalue = $(this).closest("tr").find("input").attr("value"); 
            
            $("#txtcategoryname").val(inputvalue);
        });  
        
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" style="float:right" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalitems" >Add Category</button>

    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table" id="categoryList">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Category Name</th>
                    <th>Action</th>                 
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>            
    </div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalitems" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">    
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form id="modalfrmdata">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <div>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="col-xs-3">Category Name</td>
                                <td>:</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" id="txtcategoryname" name="txtcategoryname" class="form-control" maxlength="100" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>                                  
                        </table>                       
                    </div>          
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>                
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd remove the `<input>` and adding an attribute on the `<tr>` instead, `x-index` for example. This will let you easily get the element with a CSS selector. Then, you can keep a variable `editing` to keep track of which item is being edited, or `null` for nothing. Then, if `editing` is not `null` in the modal's event handler, you can edit the item's text and its hidden `<input>`:

```js
let editing = null;

$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 0;

  $("#modalfrmdata").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let categoryname = $("input[name='txtcategoryname']").val();
    if (!editing) {
      $('#categoryList tbody').append('<tr x-index="' + String(counter) + '"><td>' + categoryname + '</td><td class="content tengah"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalitems">Edit</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-delete">Delete</button></tr>');
      $("input[name='txtcategoryname']").val('');
      counter++;
    } else {
      const item = $(`#categoryList>tbody>tr[x-index="${editing}"]`);
      item.find('input').attr('value', categoryname);
      item.find('td:eq(0)').text(categoryname);
      editing = null;
    }
  });

  $("#categoryList").on("click", ".btn-delete", function() {
    $(this).parents("tr").remove();
  });

  $("#categoryList").on("click", ".btn-edit", function() {
    editing = $(this).closest("tr").attr('x-index');
    var inputvalue = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text();
    $("#txtcategoryname").val(inputvalue);
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" style="float:right" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalitems">Add Category</button>

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table" id="categoryList">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Category Name</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalitems" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form id="modalfrmdata">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <div>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td class="col-xs-3">Category Name</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" id="txtcategoryname" name="txtcategoryname" class="form-control" maxlength="100" />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <div class="text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also noticed that your modal doesn't automatically close when submitted. I'm not good at Bootstrap, but you'll probably want to fix that.

Comment: If my answer solved your issue, then consider marking it as correct to indicate that it helped you and to guide others with the same issue in the future.

Comment: i notice a bug, when i added 2 rows data and remove first one then try to edit other data, it won't update the value

Comment: @Beginner Ah, I see the problem. Thanks for pointing that out! I've edited my answer and the issue should be fixed now.

Comment: I fixed it by using an attribute on the `<tr>` tags rather than creating a hidden `<input>` (the `:eq()` selector wasn't working properly, but using an attribute fixes this). That way also makes it easier to use CSS selectors and makes everything a bit cleaner overall too.